# Highlighting one object at a time with React

Tags: javascript, menu, onclick, reactjs

I'm pretty new to both React and Javascript, and I've started learning it by building a simple collapsible menu. It works as expected, except for that I can't figure out how to only highlight one item at a time. I suspect that the onClick method and state has to be owned by a higher level class than the sectionItem, but I'm really stuck in how to make this work. My first instinct would then be to iterate over all items in the menu every time something is clicked, and make sure that all other items are switched to active=false.

Is this the right way to think about this? Could someone explain how states work in React in this context, and how I should implement it here?

The entire code is available here: [Menu on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/aerugo/pen/gpeQaJ)

This is the code for the item I want to make highlightable. I've not yet been able to implement that only one item should be highlighted at once.

```
var SectionItem = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(){
    if(!this.state.active) {
      this.setState({
        currentItem: this,
        active: true,
        class: "sectionitem active"});
    }
  },
  getInitialState: function(){
     return {
       active: false,
       class: "sectionitem"
     }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className={this.state.class} onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.title}</div> 
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Great start! Let's walk through some problems in your code first.

#### Separation of concerns

There's no need to create your entire nested structure inside your top-most component. This is very contrived:

```
for (i=0; i < this.props.menuitems.length; i++) {
  if(this.props.menuitems[i].section !== lastSection) {
    var section = this.props.menuitems[i].section;
    var items = [];
    for (j=0; j < this.props.menuitems.length; j++) {
      if(this.props.menuitems[j].section == section) {
        var itemName = this.props.menuitems[j].name;
        items.push(<SectionItem title={itemName} key={itemName} />);
      };
    }
    sections.push(<Section title={section} items={items} key={section} />);
    lastSection = section;
  }
}
```

Quite on the contrary. You should try and make each component responsible for the rendering of their own piece of information. We could improve this if we first treated your data. The problem is that your sections are not nested. What if, instead of this...

```
var MENU_ITEMS = [
  {section: "About", name: "Hey", key: "Hey", selected: true},
  {section: "About", name: "No", key: "No", selected: false},
  {section: "About", name: "Way", key: "Way", selected: false},
  {section: "People", name: "Cakewalk", key: "Cakewalk", selected: false},
  {section: "People", name: "George", key: "George", selected: false},
  {section: "People", name: "Adam", key: "Adam", selected: false},
  {section: "Projects", name: "Pirate raid", key: "Pirate raid", selected: false},
  {section: "Projects", name: "Goosehunt", key: "Goosehunt", selected: false},
];
```

We had this:

```
var sections = [
  {
    name: "About", 
    items: [
      {name: "Hey", key: "Hey", selected: true},
      {name: "No", key: "No", selected: false},
      {name: "Way", key: "Way", selected: false}  
    ]
  },{
    name: "People", 
    items: [
      {name: "Cakewalk", key: "Cakewalk", selected: false},
      {name: "George", key: "George", selected: false},
      {name: "Adam", key: "Adam", selected: false}
    ]
  },{
    name: "Projects", 
    items: [
      {name: "Pirate raid", key: "Pirate raid", selected: false},
      {name: "Goosehunt", key: "Goosehunt", selected: false}
    ]
  }
];
```

Then we could simplify `Accordion` quite a bunch. We simply render one `Section` for each `section`:

```
var Accordion = React.createClass({  
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        {this.props.sections.map(function(section){
          return <Section key={section.name} section={section}/>
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Likewise, Section and SectionItem become quite simpler.

```
var Section = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(){
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open,
      class: this.state.open ? "section" : "section open"
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function(){
     return {
       open: false,
       class: "section"
     }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.class}>
        <div className="sectionhead" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.section.name}</div>
        <div className="articlewrap">
          <div className="article">
            {this.props.section.items.map(function(item){
              return <SectionItem key={item.name} item={item}/>
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var SectionItem = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(){
    this.setState({
      currentItem: this,
      active: !this.state.active,
      class: this.state.active ? "sectionitem" : "sectionitem active"
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function(){
     return {
       active: false,
       class: "sectionitem"
     }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className={this.state.class} onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.item.name}</div> 
    );
  }
});
```

#### Propagating state changes

Now, to your original question. In a more complex application, you could benefit from something more robust like [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-overview.html). However, for now, following the techniques exposed in [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) should solve your problem.

Indeed, one good way is to bring your state of "what is open" to the `Accordion` component. You simply need to let your parent know that something is being clicked. We can do that through a callback passed as a `prop`.

So, `Accordion` could have an `openSection` state, and an `onChildClick` that receives the clicked section's name. It needs to pass `onChildClick` to each `Section`.

```
var Accordion = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      openSection: null
    };
  },

  onChildClick: function(sectionName) {
    this.setState({
      openSection: sectionName
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        {this.props.sections.map(function(section){
          return <Section key={section.name} 
                  onChildClick={this.onChildClick}
                  open={this.state.openSection===section.name} 
                  section={section}/>
        }.bind(this))}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

And `Section` simply calls this function when clicked, passing in it's own name.

```
var Section = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(){
    this.props.onChildClick(this.props.section.name);
  },

  render: function() {
    var className = this.props.open ? "section open" : "section"
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <div className="sectionhead" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.section.name}</div>
        <div className="articlewrap">
          <div className="article">
            {this.props.section.items.map(function(item){
              return <SectionItem key={item.name} item={item}/>
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

You can extrapolate this solution to the `SectionItem` problem.

The resulting codepen is here: http://codepen.io/gadr90/pen/wamQXG?editors=001

Good luck on learning React! You are on the right path.

Comment: The OP wanted to select only one item at a time. While your codepen solution allows you to select and deselect, it does not solve for highlighting only one SelectionItem at a time.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I intentionally left this part for the OP to solve himself. Otherwise, he won't learn, will him? :)

Comment: Wow, what a great and helpful answer! I really appreciate your effort, especially with giving me some pointers with the rest of the code. I'll look into this, thanks!

Comment: Hey, it's my pleasure to help.